# Bash - how to list files with size in bytes

Tags: bash, unix

I am wanting to use the ls command to output the files in a directory however I need the file size in bytes.

Is this possible with the ls command?

on similar questions i've found this `ls -l --block-size=M` which outputs the file size in megabytes however I cannot seem to get it to work with just bytes.

Comment: What happens without `--block-size`?

Comment: @JoshLee I'm an idiot. Just realised that outputs in bytes. Is there any way to just output the bytes and filename with no other information?

Comment: See the "Getting metadata on a file" section of http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: The ls command is often aliased to something like 'ls -h' which makes it provide human readable output. If your exploring various options you may need to be sure your using the non-alias one in /bin/ls .
Using the git bash console call /usr/bin/ls -l givens the full block size 1 of files. Though as this is still the block size you might want to consider the using stat as suggested below by @William Pursell.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are looking for statistics about files, then you want to use `stat` rather than `ls`.  eg, with gnu stat:

```
stat --format=%n:%s *
```

Comment: Might specify this answer as a GNUism. (Granted, there's not much available by way of good answers that *don't* require extra tools -- if not GNU `stat` or GNU `find`, then a Perl interpreter).

Comment: ...`wc -c <"$file"` is perhaps a portable and robust way of getting a file's length, albeit one that could conceivably be wildly inefficient if run with an astonishingly bad implementation of `wc` (one that doesn't know how to either `stat` or combine `seek()` and `tell()` when handed a handle on a real file).

Comment: Does not work on macOS 12.2 (zsh)

Comment: @akauppi, that's a MacOS thing, not a zsh thing; it would fail the same way with bash on a Mac, or would succeed in zsh on a Linux distro using GNU tools. `stat` is provided by the operating system, not by the shell.

Answer (score 9):

```
$ ls -l foo.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 68964464 Mar 12  2014 foo.tar.gz
```

On my `ls (GNU coreutils) 8.26` :

```
$ ls -s --block-size=1 foo.tar.gz
68972544 foo.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -l | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f5,9-
```

`tr -s " "` replaces multiple spaces in sequence with one space

`cut -d " " -f5,9-` sets the delimeter to a space, and prints the fields 5 and 9 onwards. The 9 onwards is because filenames can have spaces in them, and just printing field 9 would on;y get the first word

Bonus: If you want to switch the output order ($filename $bytes), you can add on a

`| sed 's_\([0-9]*\) \(.*\)_\2 \1_'`

Comment: `ls` output [is not safe to parse](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). If you have GNU tools, consider `find -printf` to pass an explicit format string.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `ls -l` has a well-defined output – it's not like we're talking `for f in $(ls)` here. Personally I elected to use `sed` for this so I could keep the alignment and the `total [x]` line. Plus if my pattern matching fails, I get extra data rather than missing data.

Comment: @Sinjai The timestamp portion is not at all well-defined. That means you don't know how many words that field decomposes into, so you don't know if `5-9` refers to what you expect.

Comment: I'm not sure under what circumstances you'd run into the format differing, but I suppose for my use case (only needs to work on my machine) it's enough that it be consistent for me.