# how to add an echo to awk?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, command

I am having some trouble with my bash shell script which I am using to print the 6th and 10th fields of the ls -l command. It works as it is but I am unsure on how to add an echo to the end of it. It prints filename and size in bytes but I was wondering if I could get it to say 'BYTES' at the end of each line to make it clear what unit the file size is in.

So far I have

```
/bin/ls -ls "$directory" | awk '{print $10,$6}'
```

That isnt the whole code obviously but the only thing relevant to my question. Do I need to assign an echo to a variable and then add it or something? I am new to bash shell scripting so I am sorry if my question is bad.

EDIT:
If I use the command like this

```
wastesizeandlist ~/dev
```

The output I get is

```
This directory exists
Performing command
wastesizeandlist 520
```

I added "BYTES" within the script as somebody suggested (apologies for forgetting your name, I can't see it right now). The output now is

```
This directory exists
Performing command
  BYTES
wastesizeandlist 520 BYTES
```

Which is almost there. Apart from the BYTES under the performing command echo.
I am trying to get it to look like this

```
This directory exists
Performing command
wastesizeandlist 520 BYTES
```

And I know we shouldn't be parsing the output of ls but I have an assignment which requires me to get the file size and names of all files in a directory. If there is a better way to this, it would be appreciated if you could tell me.

EDIT:
If I try -lsR, I get an output like this

```
Filename:     Size:  BYTES
Filename: wastesizeandlist   Size: 520 BYTES
Filename: test     Size: 4096 BYTES
Filename:        Size:  BYTES
Filename:        Size:  BYTES
Filename:        Size:  BYTES
Filename: 1      Size: 5 BYTES
```

Here test is a sub directory and 1 is a file within that sub directory. What I am asking now is how would I remove the line which appears at the start and the lines which appear before a new directory? I tried the command on another directory and it has the same issue. A seemingly nameless and sizeless file at the start and then 3 after going into a subdirectory? All help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Just changed tail -n +2 to +3 and it removes the first line. How would I remove the other empty lines and put the output into proper spaced out columns?

Comment: edit your Q to include 1-2 lines of sample output from your `ls` command, then show your required output. Generally speaking `print` is the `awk` equivalent of `echo`, you should be seeing output from your current command. Please also include your current output and any description of why you think it is wrong. My recollection is that `$9` is the last fields of the `ls -ls` output. Is that your problem? Good luck.

Comment: ^ ...What he said. God bless you!

Comment: Ignoring the fact that you shouldn't be doing this at all (ie, splitting the output of `ls -l`), just do `awk '{print $10,$6,"BYTES"}'`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Could you check my edited question please?

Comment: @shellter Could you check my edited question please?

Comment: To get the names and sizes of the files, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47821353/bash-how-to-list-files-with-size-in-bytes/47822073#47822073

Comment: IOW, just do `stat --format="%n %s BYTES" "$directory"/*`

Comment: @WilliamPursell that works but it doesnt go into sub directories. How would I edit it to do that?

Comment: Also how would I make the output look neater? Like how would I make the filenames all line up in a column and the same for the file size? @WilliamPursell

Comment: If your filenames don't contain any whitespace, just do: `find "$directory" -type f -exec stat --format='%n %s BYTES' {} \; | column -t`.  If you have whitespace, maybe `find . -type f -exec printf "%50s %10d BYTES\n" "{}" "$(stat --format='%n' {} )"  \;`

Comment: Ok I tried the first bit of code and it works but it does not group files from specific directories together.. they are in the wrong order. How would I sort that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like `/bin/ls -ls | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $10,$6,"BYTES"}'` To remove the first line in the `ls` output that your `awk` command doesn't parse correctly.

Comment: i tried that and I only get one filename and its size. it has removed the BYTES under the second echo but it does not display the rest of the filenames and sizes in that directory. Sorry if I didnt say that I made more files in that directory to see if it worked for those too.

Comment: What Im saying is how would I remove the BYTES bit after the "Performing command" echo and leave everything the ls and awk return.

Comment: My bad. You should use `/bin/ls -ls | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $10,$6,"BYTES"}'` instead.

Comment: Yeah I found awk 'NR>1' aswell. It was my bad too don't worry. I should have been clearer from the start. I dont post much here thats why. Thank you though. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: The first BYTE is actually caused by the "total" line from the ls output, which confuses you awk script.

Comment: Well, (at least on my system) ls -ls starts by giving a  `total line`, such as       
    $ ls -ls \n 
    total 4 \n 
    0 -rw-r--r-- 1 khoyo khoyo   0 Dec 17 04:17 foo \n 
    4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 khoyo khoyo 144 Dec 17 04:32 tmp.sh \n

Comment: (stack overflow isn't really clear because there is no multiline in comment, but simply try a `ls -ls` in your shell.

Comment: Ah OK yeah just tried that. Same on mine. Why was that changing to BYTES though?

Comment: Well, when awk split that line, there is no field `$10` and field `$6`, so `print $10,$6,"BYTES"` just prints `  BYTES`

Comment: Ah I understand. Thank you. Would it be possible to add an empty line between each filename? So it would look something like:    file 1 200 BYTES (empty line here) file2 200 BYTES (<--- on new line)

Comment: Use `print $10,$6,"BYTES\n"` in awk ;)

Comment: That just prints it as file1 200 BYTES/n ?

Comment: Use `\ `, not `/`

Comment: Haha my bad. I really appreciate your help. Does \n work inside any echo and it will add an empty line after it? EDIT: Just tried it and it doesn't work with echo so its only for print?

Comment: Ahh I see. Thank you very much. You've been a massive help.

Comment: Would it be possible to get it to look into a directory within the directory given as the argument and list the names and file sizes of files in there too?

Comment: pluse-uno for good answer and tech support ;-/ . Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

@Lenik

Based on your question :

quote :

..............I have an assignment which requires me to get the file size and names of all files in a directory. **If there is a better way to this, it would be appreciated if you could tell me.**

END OF quote

This way you'd get the file sizes within a directory in a "human readable format", using "du" instead of "ls", as a first column. The second column would be the filename (iterate over $dir_to_check variable as needed)

```
dir_to_check="./testKalin/" ; for file in `find ${dir_to_check} -type f` ; do du -h ${file} ; done
```

10M ./testKalin/10

9.0M    ./testKalin/9

8.0M    ./testKalin/8

7.0M    ./testKalin/7

6.0M    ./testKalin/6

5.0M    ./testKalin/5

4.0M    ./testKalin/4

3.0M    ./testKalin/3

2.0M    ./testKalin/2

1.0M    ./testKalin/1

Example :

```
for dir in ./testKalin ./testKalin2 ; do dir_to_check=${dir} ; for file in `find ${dir_to_check} -type f` ; do du -h ${file} ; done ; done
```

10M ./testKalin/10

9.0M    ./testKalin/9

8.0M    ./testKalin/8

7.0M    ./testKalin/7

6.0M    ./testKalin/6

5.0M    ./testKalin/5

4.0M    ./testKalin/4

3.0M    ./testKalin/3

2.0M    ./testKalin/2

1.0M    ./testKalin/1

10M ./testKalin2/10

9.0M    ./testKalin2/9

8.0M    ./testKalin2/8

7.0M    ./testKalin2/7

6.0M    ./testKalin2/6

5.0M    ./testKalin2/5

4.0M    ./testKalin2/4

3.0M    ./testKalin2/3

2.0M    ./testKalin2/2

1.0M    ./testKalin2/1

Comment: Khoyo has been a great help and has solved my issues. Thank you for trying too. I had a look at --block-size earlier but it didnt have bytes and that is the unit which I need to display file size in for my assignment. ls -l does that anyway I'm sure so I just needed to clarify for the user what the unit is and thats why I added the BYTES bit at the end.

Comment: Do you know how I would use the way Khoyo showed me but make it so the command can look into directories within other directories. Recursively I think its called? The command works fine its just lacking that little bit.

Comment: @Lenk , ls -lsR - the "-R" option lists the sub directories recursively.

Comment: that works but it has some empty fields. It brings back an empty first line and then another empty one after it has finished listing one directory's contents. Then it lists the next directory but with another 2 empty files. I think they are hidden files which are named "." and ".."     How would I make it either show those files or hide those results? I have tried using -a but it doesnt work